# Yii2 stop user being logged out when browser is closed

Tags: php, yii2

I am having some issues with users being logged out when they close the browser. I tried to set enableAutoLogin to true but then the user never seems to get logged out even when setting authTimeout and absoluteAuthTimeout. Does anyone know how to make it so it doesnt log them out when they close the browser but logs them out after 10 hours?

```
'user' => [
        'class' => \common\models\WebUser::class,
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'authTimeout' => 36000, 
        //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'absoluteAuthTimeout' => 36000,
        'enableSession' =>true,
    ],
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
        'timeout' => 36000, // 2 weeks=
        'useCookies' => true,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this issue, the solution when using enableAutoLogin is true is to set the duration which is the second parameter when calling the login funciton

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate())
    {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 36000);
    }
    return false;
}
```